# pyserial 2.7 documentation is wrong, python 3.4 TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyserial

I am trying to run the most simplest example for pyserial 2.7 from [its webpage](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html) in the python shell:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port
>>> print ser.name          # check which port was really used
>>> ser.write("hello")      # write a string
>>> ser.close()             # close port
```

However, it is not working:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial(0)
>>> print ser.name
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>>> print (ser.name)
COM1
>>> ser.write("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ser.write("hello")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
    b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: Since the example shows Python 2 syntax, the example was probably not meant to be used with Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ser.write("Hello".encode())
```

Could you try this one, it should solve your problem. Or;

```
check.write(b"Hello")
```

I'm suspecting that needs to turn it to byte array